# Pass input type=date value to date function to get particular format

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, html

Is there any way to get input **type=date** value to javascript date function?

I have used in HTML:

```
<input type=date ng-model="dueDate">
<input type="time" ng-model="dueTime">
<button class="button button-block" ng-click="upload_duedates(dueDate, dueTime)">Add duedates</button>
```

In controller inside upload_duedates function I am getting this:

```
dueDate = Thu Jun 24 1999 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
dueTime = Thu Jun 24 1999 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

But I have to change this date format to something like:

```
dueDate = 24/01/1999 or 24-jan-1999(only dd, mm, yyyy)
dueTime = 00:00:00 (only HH:mm:ss)
```

Is there any filter/directives in **angularjs** or any way to solve this?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Thanks, the link helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many source in the web to show that. 
E.g. http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-in.html

Comment: Thanks, I got a solution from your link.